# How to find the maximum and minimum points constrained by a function.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have the function $f(x,y)=e^{x^2-y^2}$ and I would like to find the maximum and minimum constrained by the function $x^2+y^2=1$.

I've set up the following system of equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
\nabla f=\lambda \nabla g\\
x^2+y^2=1
\end{cases}
$$

Which gets me:
$$
\begin{cases}
e^{x^2-y^2}(2x)=\lambda(2x)\\
e^{x^2-y^2}(-2y)=\lambda(2y)\\
x^2+y^2=1
\end{cases}
$$

However I don't think this would get me to the solutions.

Comment: This looks terribly obvious. Just substitute the constraint into the function and you have $f(x,y)=e$ constant. Is there a typo or something?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Oh yes, there's indeed a typo. Fixed.

Comment: Maybe I’m being stupid as usual. But if $x^2 - y^2 = 1, \ $ then $f(x,y) = e^{x^2-y^2} = e^1 \ $ for all values of x and y

Comment: @AdamRubinson There was a typo. It is was not $x^2-y^2=1$, but $x^2+y^2=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x,y)=e^1e^{-2y^2}$, $0\le y^2\le1;$

$\max f(x,y) =e^1$, for $y=0,$ $(x=?);$

$\min f(x,y) =e^{-1}$, for $y=\pm 1,$ $(x=?).$

Comment: Thanks. So we actually didn't use Lagrange multipliers right?

Comment: Jonathan. No need. Turns out to be quite simple.Before doing fancy stuff, one can check if another method turns out to be simpler. Here we write ${x^2-y^2}+2y^2-2y^2=(x^2+y^2)-2y^2=1-2y^2$, only depending on y. And $0 \le y^2 \le 1$, since $y^2=1-x^2$.Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The exponential function $\exp(\cdot)$ is strictly increasing. Hence the maxima and minima of $e^{x^2-y^2}$ coincide with those of $x^2-y^2$.

We now write $u=x^2,v=y^2$. The reduced problem is now to find extrema of $u-v$ subject to $u+v=1,u\ge0,v\ge0$. This is simple – the maximum is obtained at $(u,v)=(1,0)$ and the minimum at $(u,v)=(0,1)$.

Translating back to the $(x,y)$ domain gives the maxima of $f(x,y)$ at $(\pm1,0)$ and the minima at $(0,\pm1)$.