# Finding the solutions of a system of equations

Tags: multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system

I've encountered the following system of equations from a previous question I asked ([How to find the maximum and minimum points constrained by a function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3535427/how-to-find-the-maximum-and-minimum-points-constrained-by-a-function))

$$
\begin{cases}
e^{x^2-y^2}(2x)  &= \lambda(2x)\\
e^{x^2-y^2}(-2y) &= \lambda(2y)\\
\end{cases}
$$

It turns out that if I solve for $\lambda$ I get: $e^{x^2-y^2}=-e^{x^2-y^2}$, which gets me no solutions in $\mathbb{R}$.

But, if I compare both the equations I get: $\frac{x}{-y}=\frac{x}{y}$, which does have solutions in $\mathbb{R}$.

Maybe I'm not seeing it, but how is it that?

Answer (score 2):

Your solution for $\lambda$ is wrong when $x=y=0$

Comment: I see... That's very interesting.